# Issue with Markdown Auto-link Service returning invalid URL

Tags: ruby, markdown

I'm using [Brett Terpstra's Markdown Services](http://brettterpstra.com/projects/markdown-service-tools/), and the Auto-Link Web-Search service fails to give a valid link.

Can anyone figure out what might be causing the issue?

```
require 'net/https'

def e_url(string)
    string.gsub(/([^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/n) do
        '%' + $1.unpack('H2' * $1.size).join('%').upcase
    end
end

ARGF.each do |input|
    http = Net::HTTP.new('duckduckgo.com',443)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    response = http.get("/?q=%5C#{e_url(input)}%2F")

    if response.code.to_i == 200 && !response.body.nil?
        match = response.body.strip.match(/url=(.*?)'/i)
        unless match.nil?
            print %Q{[#{input.strip}](#{match[1].strip})}
        else
            print input
        end
    else
        print input
    end
end
```

The above script returns the following when run on the string *Google*:

```
[Google](/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fencrypted.google.com%2F)
```

What I was expected to get:

`[Google](https://encrypted.google.com/)`

The script is a quick way to make links in a markdown text using the first result in duckduckgo.

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Comment: What is expected to be the output the original string linked to the first hit on duckduckgo. In this instance: `[Google](https://encrypted.google.com)`

Comment: You have Google variable instead of "Google" string, so you can have unexpected results and exceptions with nil object. Please, provide detailed information about what do you want to get in results.

Comment: @EivindB Hmmm. Type `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%5Cgoogle%2F` in your browser address field and see that you yield the expected result. At least, DDG will redirect you directly there. Whether you expected to see the result of redirection, you should handle `response.code.to_i == 301` case manually.

Comment: @mudasobwa I come to the result that I'd expect, but as you can see from my example above, the script does not inject the resulting URL into a markdown link.

Comment: @funnydaredevil What more detail would like? The way I want the script to behave? I cannot give much detail about the script, because it's created by [Brett Terpstra](http://brettterpstra.com/projects/markdown-service-tools/).

Comment: @EivindB Well it does. There is redirection page you probably missed to see over the broadband. DDG **first** response is what you’ve got, with `301 REDIRECT` status. Your browser handles the `301` response and redirects you to the proper page. Your code, though, executes the latter `else print input` statement on `301` redirect instead of re-request the proper page.

Comment: @EivindB Oooups, sorry. I have examined the response throughfully; it returns `200`, I was wrong in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, DDG behave a bit strange. The response to:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new('duckduckgo.com',443)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

response = http.get("/?q=%5C#{e_url(input)}%2F")
```

is some `url` within same domain. If you do request it then:

```
match = response.body.strip.match(/url=(.*?)'/i)
response = http.get(match[1].strip) unless match.nil?
```

you’ll surprisingly get the following `request.body`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name='referrer' content='origin'>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script language='JavaScript'>
    window.parent.location.replace("https://encrypted.google.com/");
  </script>
  <noscript>
    <META http-equiv='refresh' content="0;URL='https://encrypted.google.com/'">
  </noscript>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, I would suggest you do the following (the error handling is omitted):

```
response = http.get("/?q=%5C#{e_url(input)}%2F")
match = response.body.strip.match(/url=(.*?)'/i)
response = http.get(match[1].strip)
match = response.body.strip.match(/URL='(.*?)'/i)
puts %Q{[#{input.strip}](#{match[1].strip})}

# ⇒ [google](https://encrypted.google.com/)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should contact the dev. The service has actually been deprecated because he got tired of keeping up with changes in the results he was scraping. It's been superseded by [SearchLink](http://brettterpstra.com/projects/searchlink/) (that will be made more clear soon).